# Logic: In a 2D data find and remove duplicates and average the y axis results

Tags: python, c++, c, matlab

This is my first question on this forum. I have mentioned Logic in subject line as I am not looking for a specific programming langauge. I would appreciate if someone can point out the problem with logic and how to implement it without any inbuilt functions.

Description: I have a 2d data which is x-axis and y-axis values from some lab experiment. The actual data is much larger. I am assuming that the person from field provides me the data as sorted list. For now I have just simplified it in this case. The first task is to remove the duplicates so that the end results is x = [1.5,2.4] and task 2 is to merge the corresponding y-values such that the new y = [(10+20)/2, (30+40)/2] = [15,35]. The output I get is

z = 
1.50000  2.40000
z1 = 
15  25

So, problem 1: z returns correct list but only if I have 1 set of duplicates. If the list has number repeated more than twice like [1,1,1,2,2,2],then this fails. 
problem 2: It is obvious that my averaging logic is incorrect.

So, I would appreciate if your guys can point out where am I going wrong and if there is a better way to approach this whole problem. Thank you.

```
clc
x1 = [1.5,1.5,2.4,2.4];
y = [10,20,30,40];

x = sort(x1);

n = length(x);

for i = 1:n
    for j = i+1:n
        if x(j) == x(i)
            for k = j:n-1
                num = 1;
                x(k) = x(k+1);
                Add = y(k-1)+y(k);
                num = num +1;
                y(k-1) = Add/num;
            end
            n = n-1;
            j = j-1;
        else

        end
    end
end

for i=1:n
    z(i) = x(i);
    z1(i) = y(i);
end
z
z1
```

Comment: First, welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Then, if you want a language-agnostic solution, an algorithm, then use the `language-agnostic` and `algorithm` tags. Don't spam with unrelated language tags. If you want a solution with only a specific language, again don't spam with unrelated language tags.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude my apologies for not adhering to the format. Having said that, I believe you got a good idea about what I am asking here. It should be easily verifiable in c or fortran. The reason I added a tag was so that someone would try in any laguage of his/her chosing and that should act as referance for me. Again my apologies if this was waste of your time or anyone else's. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Umm, let's see... You sorted `x` but not `y`; you want to sort them together and Matlab has a `sortrows` function that can do just that if `x` and `y` make up the columns of a matrix. So you wanna do that first, then unpack.

Now for the loop logic: you want to keep track of how many unique values of `x` you have found so far and the number of copies of the current value of `x` you have seen so far. You know without asking that these will both be `1` after the first row is processed. This is good because the first element doesn't fit nicely with our loop structure so it's good that we can exclude it from our loop.

Now, in our loop body, the first thing we do is compare the current value of `x`, `x(i)`, with the previous value, `x(i-1)`. Comparing floating point values for equality is kinda hit-or-miss so we tried out a fuzzy comparison here.

If they compare as equal, then we haven't found any more unique values of `x` but our string at the current value has gotten 1 longer, so we update that piece of information.

If they aren't equal, then we have completed our run at the previous unique value of `x`, so we put the previous value of `x`, `x(i-1)`, in its position among the unique values of `x` and average the previous `current` values of `y` and place this average in the corresponding position in the `y` array.

Having done that, we know that we have found one more unique value of `x` and the current run at duplicates of the current value of `x` is starting over at 1, so we update the values of `unique` and `current` to reflect these facts. After we are done, we just have to complete the run that was aborted by running out of `x` values and then chop the `x` and `y` arrays down to the number of unique values found.

Really a bit of a daunting task for a beginning programmer to work out in my opinion.

```
% bump.m

x1 = [1.5,2.4,1.5,2.7,1.5];
y1 = [10,30,20,40,50];

A = sortrows([x1' y1'])';

x = A(1,:);
y = A(2,:);

unique = 1;
current = 1;

for i = 2:length(x),
    if abs(x(i)-x(i-1)) < 100*eps(abs(x(i))+abs(x(i-1))),
        current = current+1
    else
        x(unique) = x(i-1);
        y(unique) = sum(y(i-current:i-1))/current;
        unique = unique+1;
        current = 1;
    end
end
x(unique) = x(end);
y(unique) = sum(y(end-current+1:end))/current;
x = x(1:unique)
y = y(1:unique)
```

Comment: Hello, and thank you for your time. I did try this logic. I however got the response as
x = [Matrix] 1 x 5
1.50000  1.50000  1.50000  2.40000  2.70000
y = [Matrix] 1 x 5
10  20  30  40  50
> FWIW, I believe unique is an inbuilt function in matlab that you used for variable assignment. I am using a mathematical tool similar to matlab that has unique as function. So I changed the variable name to typical. But the result is not what I intended for the matrix.

Comment: Also, you are right about the issue with equality when dealing with real precision. I didn't share that in original code but the data I have I am checking for tolerance as merge criteria.

Comment: sortrows is supposed to work in Octave as well. If you print out `x` and `y` after they are first defined at line 9 of my example, what do you get? Just copy and paste the first 9 lines into Octave, don't try to retype them. Also use your editor to make sure you change every instance of `unique` to `typical`. The example in my answer worked fine in Matlab for me.

Comment: I have everything same except that                                                           B = [xl', yl'];
C = sort(B);
A = C';

x = A(1,:)
y = A(2,:)                                                                                                             The reason being that this commercial product doesnt have sortrows inbuilt. But I checked A matrix should return same as A in your case. Also, your code works in Octave. But I am not sure why replacing the given line instead of sortrows doesn't work. I am just taking the transpose of that matrix.

Comment: The `sort` function sorts each column individually, which is not what you want, whereas the `sortrows` function considers the input matrix as a collection of row vectors and sorts this collection according to the values in the first column only, which is what you want. Matlab also has a syntax `[x,I] = sort(x1); y = y1(I)` which may save your butt if `sortrows` is not available.

Comment: Beautiful. I got the error in my case. Thank you very much for your time and follow up. Darn it, how do I accept this answer now.